# Merging several csv files and storing the file names as a variable - Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to append several csv files into a single csv file using python while adding the file name (or, even better, a sub-string of the file name) as a new variable. All files have headers. The following script does the trick of merging the files, but does not cover the file name as variable issue:

```
import glob

filenames=glob.glob("/filepath/*.csv")

outputfile=open("out.csv","a")

for line in open(str(filenames[1])):
 outputfile.write(line)

for i in range(1,len(filenames)):
  f = open(str(filenames[i]))
  f.next() 
  for line in f:
     outputfile.write(line)

outputfile.close()
```

I was wondering if there are any good suggestions. I have about 25k small size csv files (less than 100KB each).

Comment: Judging from your code, it looks like all files have the same number and type of columns.  Is this correct?  Are you intentionally skipping the first file?

Comment: Doesn't `filenames` contain a list of filenames you want? What more are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: @FamousJameous My mind reading skills tell me that by "storing the file names as a variable", the OP means to add a column to the output file containing the file name each line originated from.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Ah, that makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and sorry for the imprecise question. but yes, that is what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python's `csv` module to parse the CSV files for you, and to format the output.  Example code (untested):

```
import csv

with open(output_filename, "wb") as outfile:
    writer = None
    for input_filename in filenames:
        with open(input_filename, "rb") as infile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
            if writer is None:
                field_names = ["Filename"] + reader.fieldnames
                writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, field_names)
                writer.writeheader()
            for row in reader:
                row["Filename"] = input_filename
                writer.writerow(row)
```

A few notes:

- Always use `with` to open files.  This makes sure they will get closed again when you are done with them.  Your code doesn't correctly close the input files.
- CSV files should be opened in binary mode.
- Indices start at 0 in Python.  Your code skips the first file, and includes the lines from the second file twice.  If you just want to iterate over a list, you don't need to bother with indices in Python.  Simply use `for x in my_list` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simple changes will achieve what you want:
For the first line

```
outputfile.write(line) -> outputfile.write(line+',file')
```

and later

```
outputfile.write(line+','+filenames[i])
```

Comment: Note that your for-loop with an index over a range is an anti-pattern, you should use `for filename in filenames`.